# staticmethods with django webservice - unexpected behavior. Should create only 1 instance (singleton)

Tags: django, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

@staticmethod in django is not working. static method should be executed only one. However, for testing I made 3 calls in parallel, and static method was called 3 times. Following is the code and output:

Code:

```
class KafkaReceiver:
    _kafka_consumer = None
    def __init__(self, topic):
        KafkaReceiver._kafka_consumer = self.create_only_one_consumer()

    @staticmethod
    def create_only_one_consumer():
        if KafkaReceiver._kafka_consumer is None:
            KafkaReceiver._kafka_consumer = KafkaConsumer(KafkaReceiver._topic)
            print("Consumer Created......")
        return KafkaReceiver._kafka_consumer
```

Output:

```
Consumer Created......
Consumer Created......
Consumer Created......
```

Parallel call code:

```
r1 = grequests.get('http://localhost:5014/message/?message=hello', callback=do_something)#, hooks = {'response' : do_something})
r2 = grequests.get('http://localhost:5014/message/?message=helloworld', callback=do_something)#, hooks = {'response' : do_something})
r3 = grequests.get('http://localhost:5014/message/?message=hellothere', callback=do_something)#, hooks = {'response' : do_something})

grequests.map([r1, r2, r3])
```

**What is expected:**
For each call to django webservice, django creates (I think) a new thread. However, the class here should not create instance of consumer. Is it a lock issue (I tried lock and RLock, it is not working with django)

Second strange thing is on further django calls this static method is not executing.

Comment: It's possible that all three requests manage to get through the if statement before the consumer is set. What kind of lock did you try - a `threading.Lock` or a `multiprocessing.Lock`? Your app server may be using worker processes rather than threads.

Comment: threading.lock and RLock did not work at all... 
With multiprocessing.lock it is giving error: semaphore or lock released too many times

Comment: I suspect, This is somewhere related to processes/threads created by django on each webservice call

Comment: Can you show how you've used the `multiprocessing.Lock` with your existing code?

Comment: ```
    @staticmethod
    def create_only_one_consumer():
            **KafkaReceiver._lock.acquire()**
#         with KafkaReceiver._lock:
            try:
                if KafkaReceiver._kafka_consumer is None:
                    KafkaReceiver._kafka_consumer = KafkaConsumer(KafkaReceiver._topic
                    print("Consumer Created......")
            finally:
                **KafkaReceiver._lock.release()**
            return KafkaReceiver._kafka_consumer
```

Comment: code formatting not appearing in comment.. I used multiprocessing Lock.. Acquired before creating receiver and release after creating (in staticmethod)

Comment: It looks like you're also using the `with` mechanism, or have you commented that out?

Comment: **with** part is commented.. that was not working at all

Comment: How are you serving your Django site?

Comment: I am running it on 0.0.0.0 on a port. Running as python manage.py runserver